# HyperX Elite Keyboard not working correctly on macOS High Sierra

Tags: mac, keyboard-layout, macbook-pro, macos-highsierra

I have [HyperX Alloy Elite Keyboard](https://www.hyperxgaming.com/us/keyboards/alloy-elite-mechanical-gaming-keyboard-pl) to use with Linux (Ubuntu) and Windows 10, but I recently got MacBook Pro 2017 for Work and I'm unable to use this Keyboard with macOS.

When I try to setup keyboard using macOS Keyboard Wizard (by pressing mentioned keys as wizard suggests), it doesn't recognize my keyboard;

[image: Keyboard cannot be identified]

However, the keyboard is recognized in other places of the OS like;

- Modifier Key Settings

[image: Modifier Key Settings]

- System Report

[image: Keyboard Details in System Report]

But the key layout is all messed up, and keys are entirely swapped.

- <kbd>q</kbd> points to <kbd>x</kbd>
- <kbd>w</kbd> points to <kbd>4</kbd>
- <kbd>`~</kbd> points to <kbd>F3</kbd>
- <kbd>Esc</kbd> points to <kbd>]</kbd>
- <kbd>Enter</kbd> points to <kbd>[</kbd>
- <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> points to <kbd>;</kbd>

And so on...

However, <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Option</kbd> and right <kbd>Win</kbd> (which points to <kbd>Cmd</kbd>) is mapped correctly.

Also, I have basic Dell USB keyboard which works just fine, so is there any way I can make my mechanical keyboard function correctly? any help is appreciated.

**Update**

HyperX [confirms](https://twitter.com/HyperX/status/936605808552529920) that this particular keyboard is not compatible with Mac and is only compatible with Windows, but then that's the case with almost every Gaming keyboard out there, and again, even Linux support is not advertised but this keyboard works perfectly with Linux (incl. media keys).

**Update March 2018**

As per @Reno's [answer below](https://superuser.com/a/1299878/56341) this problem can indeed be fixed by flashing latest firmware to the keyboard, however, the firmware itself is nowhere listed on HyperX website, and I managed to find it from this [Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/MechanicalKeyboards/comments/79qc1l/helpfirmware_hyperx_alloy_fps_mechanical_keyboards/?ref=share&ref_source=link), and while I took the risk of updating the firmware by downloading the updater from someone's dropbox, I know it is hard to trust this method so I'm still open to answer that can point me to official HyperX page with firmware download.

Also it is worth noting that even when I updated the firmware from Windows, going back to Mac doesn't make the keyboard work, I'm still required to have Karabiner Elements app running (even after deleting all key mappings from it) to make the keyboard work which seems weird.

So as of now, this keyboard works for me on macOS High Sierra if I keep Karabiner Elements service running. Only thing that doesn't work is Play/Pause & Next/Prev buttons from media controls, even the volume knob works fine!

Comment: Can you try typing some words within a PC BIOS or very old OS (if you still have Windows XP installed) and see if it is mapped properly?

Comment: @someuser I'm not sure what you mean here, I'm new to Mac, and this keyboard works fine on Windows 7 through 10, and also in Linux.

Comment: I am suggesting that you troubleshoot by eliminating any proprietary driver that could be used automatically. BIOS menu is where you press a special key (e.g. F10) during boot. No OS from HDD involved.

Comment: @Kushal any update on the situation? I own this keyboard too and haven't tested it yet on my Mac, but it probably won't work. Did you manage to get it working or somehow map the keys to the correct characters?

Comment: @Erik I managed to make it functional using Karabiner Elements https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/, but again, not all keys map correctly, some keys are completely not being registered by Karabiner, and some keys are registered twice, so I still don't have concrete solution yet.

Comment: @Kushal After some fiddling around I think I located the source of the problem for Alloy FPS: it has two key rollover modes: 6KRO and NKRO. When connected to a Mac, if I switch to NKRO from the default 6KRO by pressing FN+DEL, I get the wrong letters. When I switch back by pressing FN+INS, everything is okay.

AFAIK, Alloy Elite does not have separate key rollover modes. The only related combination in the manual is (Brightness key + LED backlight mode key + game mode key) to reset the keyboard. Have you tried doing that?

Comment: @user140739 Please check the **Update 2018** part of my question. :)

Comment: I also tried the linked firmware update in Dropbox and I can confirm it does work.

Comment: Please quick. I have to buy a new keyboard. Does this work on mac? Willl i be able to reprogram it using windows, save settings to the keyboard, and then use the changes on a mac? I need to customize the keys completely. Thanks!

Comment: @Kushal Do you even need karabiner when you are able to reprogram this keyboard yourself? I need to  switch keys around. Create new mod keys ( say ctrl + shit becomes something else) and so forth. I use karabiner for that now but seems to be ideal always.

Answer (score 9):

I had the exact same problem with HyperX Alloy on Mac, and performing a factory reset solved it for me.

> You can perform a factory reset of you keyboard by pressing and
>   holding FN + ESC until the keyboard backlight flashes once.
>
> FAQ: KHX-082616-KB-04

Comment: I just tried factory reset of my hyperx elite alloy (by pressing and holding the three keys in the top left), but it did not help.  a still gives h etc.

Comment: this did work for me. The keyboard broke from the night to the morning, and i tried it on 2 different macs. This fixed the issue.

Comment: This worked for me too!

Comment: Please quick. I have to buy a new keyboard. Does this work on mac? Willl i be able to reprogram it using windows, save settings to the keyboard, and then use the changes on a mac? I need to customize the keys completely. Thanks!

Comment: Do you even need karabiner when you are able to reprogram this keyboard yourself? I need to  switch keys around. Create new mod keys ( say ctrl + shit becomes something else) and so forth. I use karabiner for that now but seems to be ideal always.

Comment: Had the same issue on a MacBook Pro M1 2021 running macOS 13.3.1. Resetting the keyboard fixed my issues

Answer (score 4):

I actually have an update on this.

I contacted Hyper X/Kingston and they said they said they have an updated firmware. (For both FPS and Elite keebs.)

After I flashed this firmware it worked perfectly. I am typing this post with the new firmware (version 2112). It is best that you contact Hyper X and ask them for the firmware that suits your keyboard.

After updating the firmware all keys work well. The media keys too. The windows key is now the Command key.

You will need a Windows & SP1 PC or above to flash this firmware though

But honestly I think it is Apple's fault for still supporting ADB codes which are so old.

Comment: Can you point me to firmware update page please?

Comment: Ok I managed to download firmware updater from https://www.reddit.com/r/MechanicalKeyboards/comments/79qc1l/helpfirmware_hyperx_alloy_fps_mechanical_keyboards/ which I'm not sure is trusted source, although I went ahead and risked to update firmware and viola! keyboard works on mac!! only thing that baffles me is that I have to keep Karabiner running (even if I delete created mappings from it) as otherwise keyboard doesn't work.

Comment: Re: karabiner I am not sure- I dont need karabiner anymore after the firmware update. About the right firmware, since there are different layouts for different keyboards I suggest to contact Hyper X by email with your keyboard model no. Your keyboard model no is below the keyboard on a white sticker

Comment: @Kushal you are awesome!! 

Firmware Update worked perfectly in my HyperX Alloy Cherry MX Elite (Red, not RGB Latam version). The behavior of the keys using MacOSx is exactly the same as Windows now.
Thanks for sharing this valuable information.